# paramsの使い方について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsで`link_to("○","□")`でurlの記入場所`□`に`params[:id]`は使用できないのですか?
paramsはコントローラーでしか使用できないのでしょうか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

viewで`link_to`の引数に`params`を用いることができないのか、という認識でおります。

railsではcontrollerからviewに変数を渡すには、controllerでインスタンス変数として定義する必要があります。

`params[:id]`のみをviewに渡したいのであれば、以下のようにcontrollerで`params[:id]`を値に持つインスタンス変数を定義するとviewから使えるようになります。

controller

```ruby
...
def show
  @id = params[:id]
end
```

view

```erb
<h1><%= @id %></h1>
```

ただ、`link_to`に`params[:id]`を渡したいとのことですが、そのままidをviewに渡すのではなく

1. controllerで指定されたidを持つレコードを`find`
2. 返却されたオブジェクトをインスタンス変数として定義
3. viewで`<model>_path(@<instance_variable>)`でURLを生成

というやり方が一般的かと思われます。

rails tutorialsの例([Rails のルーティング | Rails ガイド](https://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%82%84url%E3%82%92%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B))を参考にすると、

route

```ruby
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'
```

controller

```ruby
@patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
```

view

```erb
<%= link_to 'Patient Record', patient_path(@patient) %>
```

という具合にですね。